# Solving $ \sqrt{5x+1}+\sqrt{x-1}=2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

How to solve:

$$ \sqrt{5x+1}+\sqrt{x-1}=2$$

I can tell that 1 is a solution but I am not sure how to solve this algebraically, do i start by squaring both sides?

Comment: 1 is not a solution, hint: take square of both sides, move the resulting square root in one side and square again

Comment: do you mean real solutions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint:**

Since the expression involves $\sqrt{x-1}$, we must have $x \geq 1$. But in that case, $\sqrt{5x+1} \geq \sqrt6 > 2$. What does that imply?

Answer (score 2):

The pedestrian approach would be$$\sqrt{5x+1}+\sqrt{x-1}=2\\(5x+1)+2\sqrt{5x+1}\sqrt{x-1}+(x-1)=4\\
4(5x+1)(x-1)=(4-(5x+1)-(x-1))^2$$ and you have a quadratic
but for this case Théophile has a good answer

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

As $x-1\ge0, 5x+1\ge?$

So what will be the minimum value of the sum?

Answer (score 0):

> $$ \sqrt{5x+1}+\sqrt{x-1}=2$$

Squarring both sides,we get

$$ 5x+1+x-1+2\sqrt{5x+1}\sqrt{x-1}=4$$
or$$ 6x+2\sqrt{5x+1}\sqrt{x-1}=4$$
or$$ 2\sqrt{5x+1}\sqrt{x-1}=4-6x$$
or$$ \sqrt{5x+1}\sqrt{x-1}=2-3x$$

Again squarring both sides,we get

$$ (5x+1)(x-1)=(2-3x)^2$$
or$$ 5x^2-4x-1=4+9x^2-12x$$
or$$ 4x^2-8x+5=0$$

Hence the roots of the equation are:
$$x=\frac{8\pm\sqrt{64-4\cdot 5\cdot 4}}{2\cdot 4} = \frac{8\pm\sqrt{-16}}{8}$$
or$$x=\frac{8\pm4i}{8}=1\pm\frac{i}{2}$$

Comment: $1 \pm i/2$ are NOT solutions.  If you plug them into the original equation you will get $3 \pm i$ instead of $2$

Answer (score 0):

Yes squaring both sides gives:

$$ (5x + 1) + 2\sqrt{5x+1}\sqrt{x-1} + (x-1) = 4 $$

Then:

$$ (5x + 1) + 2\sqrt{(5x+1)(x-1)} + (x-1) = 4 $$

Which simplifies to:
$$ (5x + 1) + 2\sqrt{(5x^2-4x-1)} + (x-1) = 4 $$

And thus:
$$ \sqrt{(5x^2-4x-1)}  = 2 - 3x $$

Now squaring both sides again:
$$ 5x^2-4x-1  = 4 - 12x +9x^2 $$

Which gives the quadratic equation:

$$4x^2 -8x +5 = 0$$

Solving the quadratic equation gives two solutions: $x=1+i/2$ and $x=1-i/2$. So no real solutions exist.

Comment: Also $1 \pm i/2$ are NOT solutions.  In fact the original equation has no solutions at all, even in the complex numbers

Comment: Oh yes you are right. I don't understand why this doesn't work though. What step cannot be taken in the other direction?

Comment: Change the sign of one of the square roots.